My Visual Studio no show the errros in my code
I am working on a project in Visual Studio, and I encountered a problem where the editor doesn't display error messages for certain issues, such as when a product does not exist in the code. I expected VS to highlight the line with the error, but this isn't happening.
Image of error

I have had this issue many times, are you using v12+ VS 2022? For me I had to go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Editor Help and check [] Enable all features in opened files from source generators.
